# Dataset Cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have method below

```
private DataSet passwordManagement(int reseller_ID, string username, string password, int processType, DateTime? PasswordResetDate, bool? IsPasswordReset, string newPassword)
        {
            DataSet passwordManagement = new DataSet();


            SqlParameter[] PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters = new SqlParameter[8];
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters = SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(uf.SecretPass(strConn), "PasswordManagement");

            dbconn.Open();

            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[0].Value = reseller_ID; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[1].Value = username; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[2].Value = password; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[3].Value = processType; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[4].Value = PasswordResetDate; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[5].Value = DateTime.Today.AddYears(3); 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[6].Value = IsPasswordReset; 
            PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters[7].Value = newPassword; 


            passwordManagement = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(dbconn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "PasswordManagement", PasswordManagementStoredProceduredParamaters);
            passwordManagement.Tables[0].TableName = "passwordManagement";

            dbconn.Close();

            return passwordManagement;
        }
```

I try to return dataset however i get below exception

**Cannot find table 0**

What to add to code side ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check before you try to access the `dataset` -

```
if(passwordManagement.Tables.Count > 0)
     passwordManagement.Tables[0].TableName = "passwordManagement";
```

also check if your `procedure` is returning rows with passed parameters.